# jQuery - Stop previous function from continuing to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, function

I have a function that is called when a user inputs data to set an odometer (bottom of script in counter variable). If the user wants to change any of the fields they can just put some new data in the form and the odometer will reset and start again.

The problem I have is the previous function (jOdometer) is still running with previous data as well as the new set odometer. How do I stop the previous function from running and start again?

I was hoping I could do the following...

```
    $(function(){

        var counter;

        $('#submit').click(function(){

            if(counter != undefined){
                counter.stop();
            }

            // get values from user.
            var counter_start = 0;
            var counter_end = 0;
            var increment = 0;
            var delayTime = 0;
            var speed = 0;
            var extraDigits = [];

            if($('#counter_end').length > 0){
                 counter_end = $('#counter_end').val();
            }else{
                counter_end  = false;
            }
            if($('#counter_start').length > 0){
                counter_start = $('#counter_start').val();
                if(counter_end.length > counter_start.length){
                    for(i=counter_start.length+1; i<=counter_end.length; i++){
                        extraDigits = '0' + extraDigits;
                    }
                    if(extraDigits.length > 0){
                        counter_start = extraDigits + counter_start
                    }
                }
            }else{
                counter_start = 1;
            }
            if($('#increment').length > 0){
                increment = $('#increment').val(); 
            }else{
                increment = 1;
            }
            if($('#delay_time').length > 0){
                delayTime = $('#delay_time').val(); 
            }else{
                delayTime = 500;
            }
            if($($('#delay_time')).length > 0){
                delayTime = $('#delay_time').val();
            }else{
                delayTime = 1000;
            }

            counter = $('.counter4').jOdometer({
                counterStart: String(counter_start),
                counterEnd: String(counter_end),
                delayTime: parseInt(delayTime),
                increment: parseInt(increment),
                speed: parseInt(speed),
                    formatNumber: true,
                spaceNumbers: 0,
                widthDot: 10
            });
        })

    });
```

However doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jOdometer appears to have only a `.goToNumber()` method - no `.stop()` or `destroy()`.

I think the only viable approach is to replace the odometer with a fresh DOM element and then initialise it.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var c = $('#counter4').hide(),
        counter;
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var counter_start = parseInt($('#counter_start').val()) || 1;
        var counter_end = parseInt($('#counter_end').val()) || 0;
        var counter_start_digits = counter_start.toString().length;
        var counter_end_digits = counter_end.toString().length;
        var padding = [];
        if(counter_end_digits > counter_start_digits) {
            for(var i=counter_start_digits+1; i<=counter_end_digits; i++) {
                padding.unshift('0');
            }
        }
        if(counter) {
            counter.remove();
        }
        counter = c.clone().insertAfter(c).show().jOdometer({
            counterStart: padding.join('') + counter_start,
            counterEnd: counter_end || false,
            delayTime: parseInt($('#delay_time').val()) || 1000,
            increment: parseInt($('#increment').val()) || 1,
            speed: 0,
            formatNumber: true,
            spaceNumbers: 0,
            widthDot: 10
        });
    });
});
```

*untested*

Comment: The .goToNumber is what I required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `event.stopPropagation();` to stop running event  .